# Number of $5$-card hands where all $4$ suits are present

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, card-games

> A standard $52$-card deck consists of $4$ suits and $13$ ranks. Find the number of $5$-card hands where all $4$ suits are present.

---

I tried to solve it like this:

```
   _    _    _    _    _
 13c1*13c1*13c1*13c1*48c1
```

ps* _ represent cards. Why is my approach wrong in this question?

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: The correct answer is $$4\times 13^3\times\binom{13}2.$$ Alas I cannot read your answer to see whether is is correct or not.

Comment: You're double counting.  If the two cards in the same suit are the $6$ and $7$, say, you count the case where the $6$ comes first and where the $7$ comes first as tow cases, but they're really one one.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: This method overcounts.  If, say, your hand contains $2\spadesuit, K\spadesuit$...you count it once taking $2\spadesuit$ as the "extra card", the one expressed by $\binom {48}1$ and then you count it again taking $K\spadesuit$ as the extra card.  Note that you count each hand exactly twice so you can simply divide by $2$ to correct the error.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your  reply